# Images are broken when I upload them

Tags: assets, image, environmentvariables

I have just started using craft today and I have hit a bit of a bump with Images.
I created and asset for Work and set it up to point to `assets/images/work/` I was able to upload the image but when I tried to preview the 'Work' page the image was going to `/work/assets/images/work` relative URL I am guessing.
I tried then to define and environment variable like this:

```
'environmentVariables' => array(
  'baseAssetUrl'  => 'http://192.168.99.100:8080/',
  'baseAssetPath' => './',
),
```

Updated my asset group to the following:
`{baseAssetPath}assets/images/work/`
`{baseAssetUrl}assets/images/work/`

But when I try preview the page the image is broken and the variable has not been interpreted

```
<img src="{baseAssetUrl}assets/images/work/_360xAUTO_crop_center-center/test.jpg" alt="Test">
```

And I can't upload the image I get the following error message:

```
Upload failed for test.jpg. The error message was: “Error uploading 
the file: The file system path “{baseAssetPath}assets/images/work/” 
set for this source does not exist.”
```

Any ideas what am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

It was a simple misunderstanding of how the general.php should be structured.

I had `environmentVariables` outside of the `'*' => array(`

So it's now:

```
return array(
  '*' => array(
    'omitScriptNameInUrls' => true,
    'sendPoweredByHeader' => false,
    'devMode' => getenv("CRAFT_DEVMODE") == "true",
    'environmentVariables' => array(
      'baseAssetUrl'  => 'http://192.168.99.100:8080/',
      'basePathPublic' => realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).'/../../html/',
    ),
  ),
);
?>
```

Comment: I found the answer here `http://craftcookbook.net/recipes/296`

Comment: Are you storing your assets in the root directory? My asset paths look something like this `/public/assets/` or `public/media/`.